# Calculate days between 2 dates and another criterial PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new newbie to programming and I've got an error that i wasn't able to solve after hours searching.

I'm using a form to perform a search and display in a table the data, that part was fairly easy... but I also want to calculate how many days are in the final result, not in the dates I using for the first query.

The query searches for the result in days between 2 dates and from a specified company, the problem is in the final result it calculates how many days are from my result and not from the days i searched.

Example: If i search 2 dates between February 11 and February 20 Where the company = 1

If there is only 3 days result for Company 1, I want it to calculate only 3 Days.

I know my code is Wrong in that part but i just can't get it to do what i want.

Here is a little piece of my code to explain it:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

$date1 = mysql_prep($_POST['date1']);
$date2 = mysql_prep($_POST['date2']);
$latte = mysql_prep($_POST['latte']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM payroll WHERE (day BETWEEN '{$date1}' AND '{$date2}') AND (company = '{$latte}') ORDER BY day ASC ";

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);     

$woof = "SELECT SUM(hours) FROM (SELECT * FROM payroll WHERE (day BETWEEN '{$date1}' AND '{$date2}') AND (company = '{$latte}') ORDER BY day ASC) AS subt ";
$raw = mysql_query($woof, $connection);
if(!$raw) { die(mysql_error());}
$meow = mysql_result($raw, 0, 0);

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24) +1);
if(!$result) {
    echo "FAIL"; 
    } else {
    echo "<table>
<tr>
<th> Date </th>
<th> Hours </th>    
<th> Job Title </th>
<th> Job Description </th>
<th> Paid </th>
<th> For </th>
</tr>"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   

$company = $row['company']; 

 if($company == 0) {
$company = "Wilson Electric";
} if($company == 1) {
    $company = "Wilson Rental";
    } if ($company == 2) {
        $company = "Church of Christ";
        }
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class=\"center\">" . $row['day'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"center\">" . $row['hours'] . "</td>";
echo "<td style=\"padding:5px;\">" . $row['job_title'] . "</td>";
echo "<td style=\"padding:5px;\">" . $row['job_description'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"center\">" . $row['paid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td style=\"padding:5px;\">" . $company . "</td>"; 

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class=\"center\"> Total Days:  " . $days . "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"center\"> Total Hours: " . $meow . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
}
```

Thanks for Reading it, I hope someone can give me a solution, i know must be something really simple but I just couldn't figure out.

Comment: `ext/mysql` is outdated and not maintained anymore. Additional it will be deprecated with PHP5.5. Use `PDO_MYSQL`, or `MySQLi` instead. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Comment: `$woof = "SELECT SUM(hours) FROM (SELECT * FROM payroll WHERE (day BETWEEN '{$date1}' AND '{$date2}') AND (company = '{$latte}') ORDER BY day ASC) AS subt ";` I don't think this is a legal query, at least its very weird. At the `FROM` clause you should specify a table, not this. Also it may be worthwhile to check out the mysql `JOIN` statements http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html Could you include the table layout?

Comment: @AmazingDreams: That is valid syntax, but you are quite right that it is "very weird" in that it does include unnecessary constructs. The result returned by that statement can be achieved with a much simpler statement.  That same statement can also return a count of distinct values for "day".

Comment: Thanks for the tips!! I'm reading about JOIN statements now!! It's because i watched online a little course about php and mysql at lynda.com and before go to the next level  wanted to try do something else by myself... and this very weird querys is what I'm ending up getting!!! Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @AmazingDreams : here is my table layout :) http://oi45.tinypic.com/nbua29.jpg when I was asking i triyed to do the table but i could not add the html code for table :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a count of distinct `day` values that match the specification, then you could add a simple expression to the SELECT list of the "woof" SQL statement:

```
SELECT SUM(hours), COUNT(DISTINCT `day`) AS cnt_days FROM ... 

$meow = mysql_result($raw, 0, 0);
$days = mysql_result($raw, 0, 1);
```

Note that if there is more than one row that has the same `day` value (which satisfies all of the predicates), that `day` value is counted only once.  If you want a count of rows that have a non-NULL `day` value, including any duplicates, then omit the DISTINCT keyword.)

---

Note that the SQL statement could be more simply written; you could omit the (unnecessary) inline view (i.e. derived table) and the unnecessary ORDER BY ...

```
SELECT SUM(p.hours) AS sum_hours
     , COUNT(DISTINCT p.day) AS cnt_days
  FROM payroll p
 WHERE p.day BETWEEN '{$date1}' AND '{$date2}'
   AND p.company = '{$latte}'
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! i re wrote my SQL statement as you said, i will try construct my querys in diferent way now! Thank you very much for your help! Can you explain to me why you used a little p. in frount of hours, day and after payroll?? 
Sorry i just started with php and mysql 2 weeks ago.

Comment: The "little p" qualifies the column references. I assigned the alias `p` to the table in the query, and then I used that alias to qualify the columns. This is a familiar pattern, when a query references multiple tables; it avoids "ambiguous column" errors, and helps the reader understand which table contains that column. It also helps avoid some issues caused by conflicts with MySQL reserved words.

Comment: In my little search query... there is a way if I don't specify with dates is... get it using another criteria? I added a 4th criteria on the search to see if the hours for that employee is already paid or no. It's only Yes or No but I wanna be able to select something without select the date range. Like if I click only to display Unpaid hours to display it without worry about the date range. Thank you very much again!! this is being very helpful!! :) –

Answer (score -1):

May be you can use [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: Right answer for a different question.